# foreach within a class PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP and have a class, inside this class I am trying to run

```
foreach($categories as $category) { 
                public function beam_channels_setting.$category->name()
                {
                    echo "<input name='beam_plugin_options[beam_channels".$category->name"]' type='text' value='{$this->options['beam_channels.$category->name']}'/>";

                        } 
        }
```

However I keep getting this error: unexpected T_FOREACH

I understand that this is because it is looking for a function, but I do not know how to overcome this, would I put it all within another function?

### class

```
Class BEAM_Options {

    public $options;
    public $categorielist;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $args = array(
            'type'                     => 'post',
            'orderby'                  => 'name',
            'order'                    => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'               => 0, //<--IMPORTANT!!
            'hierarchical'             => 1,
            'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
            'pad_counts'               => false );
        $categories = get_categories($args);
        $this->options = get_option('beam_plugin_options');
        $this->register_settings_and_fields();
    }

    public function add_menu_page()
    {
        add_options_page('Ad Management', 'Ad Management', 'administrator', __FILE__, array('BEAM_Options', 'display_options_page'));
    }

    public function display_options_page()
    {
        ?>

        <div class="wrap">
            <?php screen_icon(); ?>
            <h2> Ad Management</h2>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php settings_fields('beam_plugin_options'); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections(__FILE__); ?>


                <p class="submit">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save Changes" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    public function register_settings_and_fields()
    {
        register_setting('beam_plugin_options', 'beam_plugin_options');
        add_settings_section('beam_main_section', 'Settings', array($this, 'beam_main_section_cb'), __FILE__); //id, title, section, callback, page
        add_settings_field('beam_refresh_time_truth','Do you want the Advertisements to Auto-Refresh?', array($this,'beam_refresh_time_truth_setting'), __FILE__, 'beam_main_section');
        add_settings_field('beam_refresh_time','Refresh Time(seconds)', array($this,'beam_refresh_time_setting'), __FILE__, 'beam_main_section');
        $args = array(
            'type'                     => 'post',
            'orderby'                  => 'name',
            'order'                    => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'               => 0, //<--IMPORTANT!!
            'hierarchical'             => 1,
            'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
            'pad_counts'               => false );
            $categories = get_categories($args);
          foreach($categories as $category) { 
        add_settings_field("beam_channels.$category->name","$category->name", array($this,"beam_channels_setting.$category->name"), __FILE__, 'beam_main_section');
        }
    }


          foreach($categories as $category) { 
                public function beam_channels_setting.$category->name()
                {
                    echo "<input name='beam_plugin_options[beam_channels".$category->name"]' type='text' value='{$this->options['beam_channels.$category->name']}'/>";

                        } 
        }
}
```

Comment: yes please show the wghole class

Comment: Can you show us more of the class?

Comment: You can't define functions in a loop like that, let alone inside a class definition.

Comment: Updated with the entire class. (I realize some parts can be streamlined)

Comment: What is it you're trying to do here? Are you attempting to create class methods for each `$category`?

Comment: In your `foreach` statement you use declaration of the method. It's a syntax error. What do you want to do?

Comment: This is a really really bad idea. You're trying to define a function inside a loop :o

Comment: Did you try to declare your inner function in your loop? Bad idea. Do it outdoor.

Comment: What I was looking to do was create multiple functions, with different names and one thing changed inside, judging by your reactions this is a bad idea, what would be the best way to do this? It is for a word press plugin and I am trying to create unique input boxes, with a unique name based on the category name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function beam_channels_setting.$category->name() {..}
```

will not works. If you want to declare your function, it must be outter of your loop.

```
public function functionName(){
     ...
}
```

and then use it in your loop:

```
foreach(...){
  $this->functionName();
}
```

in your class.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what your saying, but I am trying to find a way to create multiple similar functions, with minor variations, based upon the results of the loop, any ideas?

Comment: Look for PHP Magics functions. You could  use the magical getter and a switch case, instead of create a lot of methods with minor variations.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work, is there any other way you can think of as It needs to be different functions?

Answer (score 2):

The [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) **must** be inside a [`function`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) if it is within a `class`.

```
public function somefunction(){
 foreach(...){
  ...
 }
}
```

If you want it called every time the class is instantiated, you can use [`__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

```
public function __construct(){
 foreach(...){
  ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, foreach must be in a function. If you want it to be executed when the class is constructed, you can put it in the [__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) function.

Comment: You shouldn't put any such things as loops into the constructor. The constructor should only accept parameters and assign them to the respective fields or pass them on to be processed.